# Want paypal subscribe button to submit form in page to me before redirecting for payment

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

Hi I have a form and a paypal subscribe button in the same page. I want to subscribe button when clicked to submit the form (email it to me) before it redirects to paypal for payment.

```
<!--THE CONTACT FORM-->

  <center> 
<form action="createUser.php" method="POST"> 

<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder= "Email Address"  required  value= <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email1']); ?> > 


    <br>

    <input id="fullName" type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Your Full Name" required value= <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullName1']); ?>>

    <br>
        <input id="tel" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Your Number" required>

    <br>

    <center>

        </center>

        </form>

<!--THE CONTACT FORM-->

<!--Paypal Button-->

        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DLNYHMF3A6TUE">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" name="submit" class="paypal_btn">
</form>
    <!--Paypal Button-->
```

Comment: Place the PayPay form on the same page as the email PHP page instead of on the contact form page, and then call a JS `document.getElementById('formName').submit();`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case its a really bad solution but its possible to submit a POST to your server via AJAX before redirecting the browser to Paypal checkout.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByClassName('paypal_btn')[0].onclick = function(){
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.open("POST", "createUser.php", true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhttp.send("email="+document.getElementById('email').value+"&fullName="+document.getElementById('fullName').value+"&tel="+document.getElementById('tel').value);
}
</script>
```